# IFrame scrollbar disappears on chrome when visibility changes

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe, scrollbar

Is Google Chrome on Windows having problems to render iframe scrollbars?

I wrote a very simple code to show what is happening (at least with me on chrome 52.0.2743.82 m):

```
  <button>Toggle visibility</button>
  <br />
  <iframe scrolling="yes" seamless src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum" frameborder="0" style="width: 700px; height: 300px"></iframe>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("button").on("click", function() {
      $("iframe").toggle();
    });
  </script>
```

[Plunker link to code](https://plnkr.co/edit/92qhwZ7I6hB78GnrEt5P?p=preview/)

When the page is loaded, the iframe as it scrollbar are visible.

Hide and show the iframe clicking the button. The scrollbar disappears.

This issue apparently occurs only in chrome.

Anyone is experiencing this too? Any fixes/workarounds?

Comment: It seems that bug appeared with Chrome 52.0.2743.82  : http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.fr/2016/07/stable-channel-update.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that bug appeared with the update Chrome 52.0.2743.82 (http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.fr/2016/07/stable-channel-update.html)

One possible workaround is to use the attribute `visibility` with `position: absolute` instead of `display` to show or hide the `iframe`.

A chrome bug ticket exists for this item: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=641881

Comment: Question regarding this, the display attribute is crucial and my website cannot work without it, any alternatives to work around this bug? and also is there any information regarding a possible fix by google? are they aware of it?

Comment: I can reproduce this issue in Chrome 54, but I can't find any reported bug in https://bugs.chromium.org - does it exist or should I file a new one?

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem, and using `visibility` instead of  `display: none` wasn't an option.

My workaround was to set `overflow: scroll` on the `<body>` of the document being displayed in the iframe, whenever I set the iframe to be visible again. This seems to force the scrollbar to appear on the iframe again. You can then reset the `overflow` to its old value, and the scrollbar will remain on the iframe. You need to wait for a repaint before you can reset the `overflow`, though, so I put this in a timeout with delay 0.

```
function showIframe(iframe) {
    var iframeBody = iframe.contentDocument.body;
    $(iframe).show();
    var oldOverflow = iframeBody.css("overflow");
    iframeBody.css("overflow", "scroll");
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        iframeBody.css("overflow", oldOverflow);
    }, 0);
}
```

There is a "flash" of scrollbar with this workaround if the iframe in question doesn't need to scroll, though, so it might be worth using the `visibility` workaround for that brief moment where the repaint is required, to avoid the flash.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround I've developed for an application I'm building. It has multiple `<iframe>` elements in a Foundation tab-control.

I used `MutationObserver` to observe when the `<iframe>`'s parent element (a Foundation `div.tabs-content div.content` element) becomes `active`, then I toggle the `iframe`'s document's `overflow` property. The runtime effect is imperceivable.

I originally wanted to `observe` the `<iframe>` directly, however no DOM mutation events were raised when the iframe itself's changed `display` property, I guess because technically speaking `element.style` values are not part of the DOM-structure proper.

Here's my code (Vanilla.js, no jQuery). If you're using in your application you will want to replace my visibility-detection code with something that is applicable to your document:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {

    var observer = new MutationObserver( onContentMutated );
    var options = { attributes: true, childList: false, characterData: false, subtree: false, attributeFilter: ['class'] };

    var iframeContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-content .content');
    for(var i = 0; i < iframeContainers.length; i++) {

        observer.observe( iframeContainers[i], options );
    }
});

function onContentMutated(mutations) {

    for(var i = 0; i < mutations.length; i++) {
        var m = mutations[i];

        var thisIsNowAnActiveTab = m.target.classList.contains('active');
        if( thisIsNowAnActiveTab ) {
            // get the corresponding iframe and fiddle with its DOM

            var iframes = m.target.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
            if( iframes.length == 0 ) continue;
            var iframe = iframes[0];

            iframe.contentWindow.document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';

            // the timeout is to trigger Chrome to recompute the necessity of the scrollbars, which makes them visible again. Because the timeout period is 0 there should be no visible change to users.
            setTimeout( function(s) {

                s.overflow = 'auto';

            }, 0, iframe.contentWindow.document.documentElement.style );
        }

        console.log( m.type );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the given example you can do: 
`$("iframe").toggle(1)`
In my case, it worked by setting back the height:
 
`$("iframe").css("height", "100%")`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Chrome with an iframe embedded into a jQuery UI tab. When  the tab containing the iframe is first displayed, the scrollbar appears. But when I switch to another tab and back to the tab with the iframe then the scrollbar disappears. All the solutions proposed here didn't work for me.
Here is what I did to fix the issue :
First, I create the tabs :

```
$("#mytabs").tabs();
```

Then I bind a function to the event "tabsactivate" and I check if the target tab is the one containing the iframe. If it is the case I call a function fixChromeScrollBar() described later on :

```
$("#mytabs").on("tabsactivate", function(event, ui) {
    if ($(event.originalEvent.target).attr("href") == "#mytab-with-iframe") {
        fixChromeScrollBar();
    }
});
```

And finally here is the function fixChromeScrollBar() which sets the overflow style attribute of the iframe body (as already said) to either "scroll" or "auto". I noticed that when I only define the "auto" or "scroll" value then if I switch to another tab and back to the iframe I lose the scrollbars. The only way to maintain them is to alternate between the two values each time the iframe appears. It is weird but it works :

```
function fixChromeScrollBar() {
    var iFrameBody = $("#myiframe").contents().find("body");
    var originalOverflow = $(iFrameBody).css("overflow");
    if (originalOverflow == "visible" || originalOverflow == "auto") {
        $(iFrameBody).css("overflow", "scroll");
    } else {
        $(iFrameBody).css("overflow", "auto");
    }
}
```

You can notice that this method is called only if you switch to the tab containing the iframe so if you click multiple times on this tab without switching to another one this code will only be executed the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently setting `src` refreshes iframe in chrome, for given example code will be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("button").on("click", function() {
        $('iframe').toggle().attr('src', function(i, val) { return val; });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Care to explain why it works rather than only posting code?

Answer (score 0):

I adapted Dai's example to my own React IFrame component. I have an iframe within a tab panel, which is itself in a collapsible panel. When either of those get toggled, I force the iframe to repaint. It works wonderfully.

```
private iframe: HTMLIFrameElement;
private displayObserver: MutationObserver;

componentDidMount() {
    // Detect style attribute changes for the containing collapsible components
    // If the display goes from 'none' to something else, then we need to redraw the iframe
    // so we get the scrollbar back as it should be.
    if (isChrome()) {
        this.displayObserver = new MutationObserver(this.onContentMutated);
        const options = { attributes: true, childList: false, characterData: false, subtree: false, attributeFilter: ['style'] };

        const tabPanelAncestor = this.findAncestor(this.iframe, '.tab-panel-content');
        if (tabPanelAncestor) {
            this.displayObserver.observe(tabPanelAncestor, options);
        }
        const collapsibleAncestor = this.findAncestor(this.iframe, '.collapsible');
        if (collapsibleAncestor) {
            this.displayObserver.observe(collapsibleAncestor, options);
        }
    }
}

private readonly onContentMutated = (mutations: Array<MutationRecord>) => {

    R.forEach( (mutation) => {
        const targetElement = mutation.target as Element;
        const style = targetElement.getAttribute('style');
        if (style && !style.match(/display: none/)) {
            this.iframe.contentWindow.location.reload(true);
        }
    }, mutations);
}

private readonly findAncestor = (element: HTMLElement, sel: string): Node | null => {
    if (typeof element.closest === 'function') {
        return element.closest(sel) || null;
    }
    let ancestor: HTMLElement | null = element;
    while (ancestor) {
        if (ancestor.matches(sel)) {
            return ancestor;
        }
        ancestor = ancestor.parentElement;
    }
    return null;
}
```